# PHP Parsing JSON to HTML Table multi dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following JSON Data:

```
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "PrimaryResult",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "TimeGenerated",
          "type": "datetime"
        },
        {
          "name": "Computer",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "2022-12-03T21:58:48.519866Z",
          "DESKTOP-KAFCPRF"
        ],
        [
          "2022-12-03T21:58:48.5198773Z",
          "DESKTOP-KAFCPRF"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using this to and trying to find a way to parse the columns as tables headers(TH) and the row data as(TR).

This is what I have:

```
  $jsonObjs = json_decode($data, true);
  echo "<pre>" . var_dump($jsonObjs) . "</pre>";
  foreach($jsonObjs as $a){
      foreach($a[0] as $b) {
        foreach($b[1] as $key => $value){
          echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br />";
        }
      }
  }
```

but my results are coming up like:

```
name : Computer
type : string
0 : 2022-12-03T21:58:48.5198773Z
1 : DESKTOP-KAFCPRF
```

Comment: You need to run through this twice.  First, extract the "columns", so you know how to label the header row of your table.  Then, just run through the "rows" list to do your printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a loop that will go through the columns and rows. From here it's fairly simple to adjust the logic for building a table. If you need any further help, let me know.

```php
foreach($jsonObjs["tables"] as $a)
  {
    // Columns
    foreach($a["columns"] as $key => $value)
    {
        $cName = $value["name"];
        $cType = $value["type"];
        
        echo("Column name is: ".$cName);
        echo("Column type is: ".$cType);
    }
    
    // Rows:
    foreach($a["rows"] as $key => $value)
    {
        $rValue1 = $value[0];
        $rValue2 = $value[1];
        
        echo("Row: " . $rValue1 . " | " . $rValue2);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot. Much cleaner then the solution I originally discovered! :)